# Calculate average wait time per day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a structure of:

```
date        | customerID    | arrivalTime       | servedTime     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-01  | 0001      |2018-01-01 18:55:00| 2018-01-01 19:55:00|
2018-01-01  | 0002      |2018-01-01 17:43:00| 2018-01-01 17:59:00|
2018-01-01  | 0003      |2018-01-01 14:01:00| 2018-01-01 14:10:00|
2018-01-02  | 0004      |2018-01-02 09:22:00| 2018-01-02 10:00:00|
2018-01-02  | 0005      |2018-01-02 12:34:00| 2018-01-02 13:10:00|
2018-01-02  | 0006      |2018-01-02 18:54:00| 2018-01-02 19:00:00|
```

I'm trying to produce a query that leaves me with two columns:

```
date  | averageWaitTime
-------------------------
```

I can then use this structure to create a chart. I can't work out how to combine the `AVG` with the `GROUP BY` and get the required result.

I initially tried to do this using a minutes value I am using elsewhere in my application produced from the following query:

```
cast(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (servedTime - arrivalTime )) as integer)/60
```

but this still a record per customer rather than by day.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: `time_of_clerking` and `patient_arrival_time` are not in your initial data set... how do you want to calculate `averageWaitTime`?.. what is the formula/logic?..

Comment: Apologies, that was taken from another part of an application. I'm not sure what the formula logic should be. I think I need the wait time per customer (the difference between servedTime and arrivalTime) and then work out what the average of all customers wait times were by date to produce a 'date' and 'averageWaitTime' result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to convert to seconds to sum time interval - just use `interval` data type.

calc (I named columns as first letter of your columns):

```
t=# select d,c,avg(s-a) from t group by d,c order by d,c;
     d      |      c      |   avg
------------+-------------+----------
 2018-01-01 |  0001       | 01:00:00
 2018-01-01 |  0002       | 00:16:00
 2018-01-01 |  0003       | 00:09:00
 2018-01-02 |  0004       | 00:38:00
 2018-01-02 |  0005       | 00:36:00
 2018-01-02 |  0006       | 00:06:00
(6 rows)
```

your result:

```
t=# select d,avg(s-a) from t group by d order by d;
     d      |   avg
------------+----------
 2018-01-01 | 00:28:20
 2018-01-02 | 00:26:40
(2 rows)
```

simple arithmetical check:

```
t=# select interval '01:00:00' + '00:16:00' + '00:09:00';
 ?column?
----------
 01:25:00
(1 row)

t=# select interval '01:25:00'/3;
 ?column?
----------
 00:28:20
(1 row)
```

which is correct, because:

```
t=# select 85/3.0;
      ?column?
---------------------
 28.3333333333333333
(1 row)
```

and 0.3(3) is one third, which is 20 seconds, 28 minutes, 20 seconds

of course I'm calculating arithmetic average - as it is the most common, so if you don't specify one it is assumed...